# Can we call http servlet from httpClient Componet

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, struts2

I want to call http servlet class from my httpClient, my httpClient code below

```
public class ConnectionClientHttp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       

    HttpParams params = new SyncBasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        //Set more parameter if necessary

        HttpProcessor httpproc = new ImmutableHttpProcessor(new HttpRequestInterceptor[] {
                // Required protocol interceptors
                new RequestContent(),
                new RequestTargetHost(),
                // Recommended protocol interceptors
                new RequestConnControl(),
                new RequestUserAgent(),
                new RequestExpectContinue()});

        HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor();

        HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(null);

        HttpHost host = new HttpHost("IPAddress", Port);

        DefaultHttpClientConnection conn = new DefaultHttpClientConnection();
        ConnectionReuseStrategy connStrategy = new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy();

        context.setAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_CONNECTION, conn);
        context.setAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST, host);

        try {
            if (!conn.isOpen()) {
                Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), host.getPort());
                conn.bind(socket, params);
            }

   BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest request = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest("POST","/");

        StringEntity myEntity = new StringEntity("Some string to send at server");
        request.setEntity(myEntity);
        request.setParams(params);
        httpexecutor.preProcess(request, httpproc, context);
        //Response from Server
        HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute(request, conn, context);
        System.out.println("<< Response: " + response.getStatusLine());                

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }// end of static void main

}// end of class
```

When I use

```
BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest request = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest("POST","<uri>");
```

above in URI I need to give the path of target class, but in my case its just a servlet file, deployed at server, which will get the request from this file and display contents at console.  
 
My problem is what path should be given? As per my knowledge in URI, it takes path as `http://localhost:8080/erik/loginSubmit!loginDetails.do` but given example is in Struts2 but if I just want to execute some servlet file which extends **HttpServlet** then what path I should give and how this file will know which file is the target to send data?

I've created Target file as below :

```
public class ExampServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Received Request and display it at console    
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Tapan

Comment: Did you try passing same path for URI? it should work.

Comment: yes it works but these details are configured in struts.xml file which  have <result> tag belongs to some JSP which i don't need cause i just wanted to execute Servlet which will just read the request and get the details, no <result> is required and i think if we configure anything in Struts.xml we have to mention <result> tag as well. thanks for your answer....